# how to subtract count values in hive in same table same column

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, apache-pig

[hi the screenshot I uploaded is table with first column post_id, score, answerCount, CommentCount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVW53.png)
hi I am stuck on a hive problem I am very noob in sql and hive I am working on stack overflow dataset, I am trying to find percentage of questions answered. what I did is I counted all the questions and counted all the questions which has been answered but I am stuck on how to subtract them

```
select AnswerCount
> from posts
> LEFT JOIN posts
> ON AnswerCount = AnswerCount
> WHERE AnswerCount IS NULL;
```

I want the result to be count of all - count of question answered
some of the answerCounts are null I did this to count answers with

```
`select AnswerCount
>from posts
>where AnswerCount > 0;`
```

here is the schema

```
post_id score AnswerCount CommentCount
385106    2       NULL        0
385107    2        0          2
385108   14       NULL        4
385109   -2       NULL        3
385110    8       NULL        5
385113   -8       NULL        2
385114   16       NULL        0
385116   30        2          6
385118   -2       NULL        0
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  A self join doesn't seem likely in this case.

Comment: hi please click the link to see the screenshot. Thanks for reply.

Comment: Please provide the schema and the data directly in your post, _not as a screenshot_.

Comment: your schema does not contain any information about the questions. where are they?

Comment: you mean the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated my answer to clean it up.

This checked out:

```
    SELECT 
    CAST(( SELECT COUNT(ua.post_id) FROM posts ua 
    WHERE ua.AnswerCount IS NOT NULL) AS DECIMAL(3,2)) / 
    CAST(COUNT(t.post_id) AS DECIMAL(3,2))
      FROM posts t
```

The query contains a sub query which selects the `COUNT()` of posts where `AnswerCount IS NULL`, it divides that by the total number of posts. The rest is to `CAST` the integers to `DECIMAL` since a factional result will be reported as `0` if left as an `int`.

Comment: If I understand your issue... you don't `COUNT()` the answers, you `COUNT()` the number of questions that have one or more answers.

Comment: yes.. count the rows and count the rows with answer count > 0 and then divide them

Comment: the query doesn't make sense. it always yields percent_answered=1

Comment: each row is going to join with itself. what's the point of doing that?

Comment: could you please explain how to calculate COUNT(ua.post_id).. I know ua as you explained unanswered but ua.post_id will it create a new table or I do not understand this syntax

Comment: @AmandeepBaberwal you haven't formulated exactly what you're trying to find. you want to find count(AnswerCount=null)/count(all) ?

Comment: here is the link to data... its in zip file under posts.xml

Comment: yes count(AnswerCount=null or AnswerCount == 0) / count(AnswerCount)

Comment: @AmandeepBaberwal it should be as simple as my posted answer.

Comment: Sorry, I should have tried my answer. The final edit does work. (I tried it on sample data).

Comment: what's the need to run 2 queries if it can be done by a single query?

Comment: @mangusta yeah it works now.. thank you so much for the helping me out..

Comment: @mangusta could you please explain the code briefly if you have some time.. thanks

Comment: I cleaned up my answer and added a brief explanation.

Comment: No problem. Please mark the answer as solving your question if it did so.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(if(AnswerCount IS NULL OR AnswerCount = 0, 1, 0))/COUNT(*) * 100 as Percent_unanswered
      FROM posts;
```

Comment: I think this results in `0` if you don't `CAST` to `DECIMAL`.

Comment: @daShier there's no need to cast

Comment: I tried your query on a temp table I created in SQL Server and it returned `0`, so I'm not sure what I did wrong.

Comment: @daShier probably there was no qualifying row. in any case the cast is not needed